# Edit data from search result? MS Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

Have a search form in Access 2016. Trying to make search result data editable in the form.

So, I'm quite new to Access 2016. I have created a database and a form for the user to enter new data + a form to search in the data using a case number. If the number matches, the result will be displayed in combo boxes in the form.

The displayed data cannot be edited, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

I've looked long and hard on the internet, but have so far only seen one video on Youtube, where the guy was showing what I'm trying to do.. But he neglected to explain in any way how he had gotten his result.

How can I create my form, so that the user can edit any search result displayed in the same form? Can I archieve this using combo boxes or am I going about it wrong?

Comment: Need to find record. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: The search form in the link doesn't allow me to edit the search result, so not entirely sure how to use it.
Edit: I can probably go about the whole thing using a couple of different forms and have the user edit data directly in the table, but an editable search result would be a lot more preferable.

Comment: Allen's example has data controls set as Locked Yes. Change that and data will be editable.

Comment: correction from my side; I'm using list boxes, not combo boxes in my search form. However, the list boxes are already unlocked, but data is not editable. They are all unbound. Is that where my fault is?

Comment: Controls used to input search criteria should be UNBOUND, otherwise you change record with the search parameter. If you want to edit retrieved record, then edit in BOUND controls, not in the search controls. Allen's example can demonstrate that.

Comment: Allen's example isn't editable for me - I can only enter what to search for, but can't edit the data in the bound fields. However, I think I understand where I need to go - thank you!

Comment: As stated in earlier comment, set the BOUND controls Locked property to No and then data is editable.

Comment: Just to make sure we're not talking about two different things, I've linked to an image where I've highlighted the "locked" control I'm referring to.. https://imgur.com/a/RlJ9fVA

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  You don't want to use bound controls in a form, ever.  It's lazy and dangerous.  You should always use unbound controls with an "Update" button, which will have code behind it to make sure that all the choices are legitimate and prompt the user to make sure they definitely want to make the changes.  Then you would update the data based on some ID field which would be the row identifier.  Using bound controls makes the changes permanent as soon as you make a choice, and backing out of those changes is a bit dodgy at best.

Comment: I was only using a test-database, so no damage done. But now at least it partly makes sense why it wouldn't work :) 
so, using unbound controls and an update button, I should be able to (at some point), fetch data using a query and then edit that data in the same fields?

Comment: I have to disagree with @JohnnyBones. I have never use UNBOUND controls for data entry/edit. Takes a lot of code to save and retrieve records. I know some developers do that. Depends how much code you want to write. I have code that allows users to 'back out' of data entry/edit. Involves a lot less code than retrieving record(s) and displaying in UNBOUND controls. The main reason to use Access as GUI is that Access can do a lot of the 'heavy lifting' for you. That image is nothing like the Allen Browne example.